# how to ignore line break in text search?

Tags: xml, maven, sed, replace

Using `sed`, I want to search a string and replace that with other in maven pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<version>3.1</version>
```

with

```
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<version>4.1</version>
```

I wrote

```
find . -name 'pom.xml' -type f -exec sed -i "s!"<groupId>com.abc</groupId>\n
<version>3.1</version>"!"<groupId>com.abc</groupId>\n    <version>4.1</version>!" '{}' \;
```

But it never works!

Comment: `sed` is not the best tool for multiline editing. Try using `perl` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `N` command to read the next line. Take a look at the excellent [Sed and Awk](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch06_01.htm) book for more details on handling multiline pattern spaces. It is a bit fiddly.

Save this sed command to a file e.g cmd.txt

```
/<groupId>com.abc<\/groupId>/{
N
s/<groupId>com.abc<\/groupId>\n<version>3.1<\/version>/<groupId>com.abc<\/groupId>\n<version>4.1<\/version>/
}
```

Then run:

```
$ sed -f cmd.txt pom.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sed for this. linebreaks are part of who sed is. This is a job for xslt.

The following code snippet was borrowed and tweaked from http://chrisdail.com/2009/05/17/changing-maven-pom-versions-with-groovy-and-xslt/

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="version[../groupId='com.abc']">
        <version>4.1</version>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Just do xsltproc thisfile.xsl pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... Hope it helps.

```
sed -e 's/3.1/4.1/g' pom.xml > pom1.xml
```

Comment: Can't use this because there are more than one dependency that are version 3.1. need to search for the group id as well

Comment: In that case, you will have to use Perl as @mouviviel mentioned for multiline search with multiple patterns.